# Generate pdf with barcode in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, barcode, node-pdfkit

I am using https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit to generate PDF files which I can do simply with something like

```
app.get('/get-pdf', (req, res) => {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const filename = 'my_pdf.pdf';

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

  const content = "Some content";

  doc.y = 300;
  doc.text(content, 50, 50);
  doc.pipe(res);
  doc.end();
});
```

But I also want to generate an UPC-A barcode:

[image]

I have found the library https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode which can generate such barcode from just the 12-digit code. However, it seems the library is mainly used in the client.

I want to generate a PDF with such barcode, but I don't know how to do it or if JsBarcode isn't too complex for just this single type of barcode.

## Edit

As suggested in the comments, I did try to generate a the barcode with the UPC-A font:

```
app.get('/get-pdf', (req, res) => {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const filename = 'my_pdf.pdf';

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

  doc.font('/fonts/UPC-A.ttf').fontSize(50).text('012345678905');
  doc.pipe(res);
  doc.end();
});
```

from which I get

[image]

which does look good, but it doesn't look exactly like common UPC-A barcodes.

I used the font at http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/UPC-A/.

Comment: did you try loading UPC-A fonts and rendering text with it? here is the documentation on how to use fonts  http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#fonts

Comment: Good suggestion! But would it be sufficient? See my edit

Comment: I think you just will have to find the right fonts which gives the same result as you want

Answer (score 2):

Download `ttf` font file for barcode  from google font : https://fonts.google.com/?query=barcode (based on your requirements)

in my case i only want barcode without text , so im using https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39

put this ttf font file in side `public/fonts` folder

```
  doc.font(__dirname+ "/../../public/fonts/LibreBarcode39-Regular.ttf").fontSize(20).text(012345678905);
```

it will generate below barcode :

[image]

if you want to use barcode with text then use this font : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39+Text

Comment: can you share the cdn of it?

Answer (score 1):

I used JSBarcode and Canvas to generate Barcode within pdf.

You need to install JSBarcode for this:

```
npm install jsbarcode
```

Code to generate barcode inside PDF:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
JsBarcode(canvas, "3000001", {
    format: "ean8", height: 20,
    displayValue: false
});
doc.image(canvas.toDataURL(), 10, 10, height:30, width:130);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used `JsBarcode` so I can't help you with this lib. But the logic is to get the Base64 String of the code bar and add it to your pdf like an image.

I use the npm module [`rescode`](https://github.com/epha/code-rescode) for doing that in my project. The code below generate a ean8 code bar and add this image in the PDF and it's work fine.

```
codes = require('rescode')
codes.loadModules(['ean8'])
dataEan8 = codes.create('ean8', '12345678')
doc.image(dataEan8, 10, 10, height:30, width:130)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the right font file (your `UPC-A.ttf` in this case) is not enough, the numbers also need to be encoded correctly.

With this TTF file, the following code works (assuming that `barcode` is already a 12-digit string including a correct check digit - if not, you can use something like the npm module `cdigit` to calculate the check digit first):

```js
const barcodeEncoded =
  // First digit including leftmost bar
  String.fromCharCode(Number(barcode[0]) + 0x50) +
  // Regular digits in the left half
  barcode.slice(1, 6) +
  // Middle bar
  'p' +
  // Differently encoded digits in the right half
  barcode.slice(6, 11).split('').map(x => String.fromCharCode(Number(x) + 0x40)).join('') +
  // Last digit including rightmost bar
  String.fromCharCode(Number(barcode[11]) + 0x60)
```

With this, `012345678905` turns into `P12345pFGHI@e` which will then be a valid UPC-A barcode with this font.

For more information, check the [readme of the font](http://www.eventgest.com/COMUNS/utils/fpdf/ttffonts/readmeean.txt) and this [article about how such barcode is constructed](https://www.morovia.com/kb/Manually-Creating-Barcode-Strings-EAN13-UPCA-Barcodes-10024.html).